# How to execute commands? via singleton utility method or via OnPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Assume one of the ViewModel receive some command that is pretty general to application (and can be also executed from other ViewModels, for example "stop ftp server"). What should i do?

- propogate `OnPropertyChanged` event to container, execute command in some top-level view (`MainWindowViewModel`)
- pass some "singleton service layer" class to each `ViewModel`, execute static method directly in the `ViewModel`, like `Utils.StopFtpServer()`
- other?

Comment: Views should be responsible for as little application logic as possible that has nothing to do with views.  An FTP server has nothing to do with a View.  But I personally dislike singletons, so I wouldn't use that option either.  In your example I'd prefer to create an `FtpServer` class that had a `Stop` method, and pass an instance of it to all view models that cared that it existed.  I'd also pass it to those view models via Dependency Injection, so I could mock out substitute its implementation in the future.  How view models know to call stop is another question, tho - can you explain?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. How does the ViewModel receive the command "Stop ftp server"?

Comment: Hmmm Why would the View Model recive this message unless it was of particular concern to it - in which case someone would listening for the command also.

Comment: Executing it in the MainWindowViewModel would be better as it would be more centralized..and also as the stop ftp server is more specific to the application and not any particular views as specified by you..!!

Comment: One of windows in my application has button "Stop ftp server", when user clicks it - ViewModel receives corresponding command via binding

Comment: Please put some code in here. It's hard to examine what you are exactly asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static commands are used by Microsoft. Therefore, it can't be a bad idea to use a static class which defines all these *global* commands.

To give an example about what I've said:

```
    EditingCommands.AlignLeft
```

This is a static class that offers *global* command used for text edition.

That said, I'll advice to avoid to put business logic into commands. Encapsulate it into Business objects and call these objects from the command. That way you'll decouple the Gui and the Business and have a more testable application.

Comment: "Singleton Service Layer" - Never heard of that.  Can you provide a link?

Comment: I repeated the OP concept's name and I put it in italic to indicate it is not the official name for this. I'll edit my post to avoid further misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do things the MVVM way, then you shouldn't stuff this into the View or the View Model, or a static method or Singleton.

An FTP server should be a full-blown Model class.

- The View should tell the View Model that it wants to execute the `StopFtpServerCommand`
- The View Model should tell the `FtpServer` instance that the FTP server should `Stop`

This means you will support multiple instances of FTP servers, even if you won't expose that support through the UI.

If you go this route, you will avoid painting yourself into a corner in the future when you decide you want multiple FTP servers.  It will force you to write a better abstraction for your class so you'll be more likely to reuse it in future programs.

It also shouldn't be very challenging to write compared to writing a Singleton, or static methods.

If you need to access the same instance from multiple view models (which your question didn't seem to require), that's a separate challenge.  I personally suggest using things like [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to solve this, so you're not calling `new FtpServer()` from inside your View Models.

Answer (score 0):

Of the two go with propagating the event. Singleton are a test unfriendly construct, and you really don't to do test unfriendly feature - like stopping or starting some service. inside such a contructs.

This answer does not relate specifically to MVVM in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Command="{Binding {x:Static business:MyStaticClass.MyStaticCommand}}" />
```

Something like that? Assuming you have the logic in MyStaticClass, which should be in the business layer